# Why is my chrome password manager and other apps take 2+ minutes to open?

Tags: chrome-for-android, performance

Galaxy S20 5G

This started happening a few months ago. Not sure if it was an android update or not.

When I try to open password manager in chrome it spins and I have to wait 2+ mins- it eventually does open.

I've noticed this with other apps like youtube as well.

I don't think my phone is under load.

Could it have been a recent update? What is the best way to troubleshoot this kind of thing? My phone isn't crashing, while it spins my pod cast app continues to play audio without hiccups so I don't think its the OS lagging.

Its like it just wants to wait several minutes before loading some apps.

Comment: If this happens with apps from Google the used Google account may have problems. Check Android settings -> Accounts -> Google account when it had been synced successfully the last time.

Comment: Could it be that some connections to Google domain/IP addresses are blocked by something, and thus waiting to timeout? Have you tried with other internet connection?